# What type of phrase is "A few days ago, ..." or "Last Monday, ..."?

Tags: phrases, time, prepositional-phrases, adjuncts, measure-phrases

What do you call a phrase like "A few days ago, ..." or "Last Monday, ..."?

For example, "A few days ago, I went shopping" or "Last Monday, I finished reading my book"

I was thinking that it was an appositive, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "A few days ago" is a preposition phrase and "last Monday" is a noun phrase. They are both functioning as temporal adjuncts in your examples..

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/600100/2085).

Answer (score 0):

An [appositive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appositive) contains two nouns, so the phrases, which you gave as examples, are not appositives.

I don't think, there is a general term for this kind of phrases.

Answer (score 0):

I would call them adverbial phrases [of time]; "temporal adjunct" describes their particular function. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase

Comment: Categorywise, they are PP and NP respectively.

Comment: Only if one buys into the notion that "ago" is prepositional.